# how to convert FormControl to TextField Material Ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

this is the old Code from some project:

```
<FormControl fullWidth><InputLabel className = {classes.inputLabel} >نوع فرم نامه</InputLabel>
    <Select TabIndicatorProps={{style: {backgroundColor: themeStyle.placeHolderTextColor}}}
    native autoFocus id="letILetTvCodeInt" onChange={this.handleChange} >
    {Tools.GetSelectOptions(this.state.LetType, 'LetTVCodeInt', 'LetTNameStr')}</Select>
</FormControl>
```

I want to change the underline color of this `select`, I know I should use TextField, but this is working fine and I just want to change underline color of this, this is the style I use for underline color in TextField
[image]

```
const styles = theme => ({
    cssLabel: {
        color: themeStyle.textFieldUnderLineColor,
        "&.Mui-focused": {
          color: themeStyle.tabIndicatorProps,
        }
    },
    cssFocused: {},
    underline: {
        '&:before': {
            borderBottomColor: themeStyle.textFieldUnderLineColor,
        },
        '&:after': {
            borderBottomColor: themeStyle.tabIndicatorProps,
            color: themeStyle.tabIndicatorProps,
        },
        '&:hover:before': {
            borderBottomColor: [themeStyle.appBarRDbgk, '!important'],
        },
        color: themeStyle.dialogContentColor,
    },
    notchedOutline: {
    },
    outlinedInput: {
        '&$focused $notchedOutline': {
            border: `2px solid ${themeStyle.tabIndicatorProps}`
        },
        backgroundColor: themeStyle.bkgBodyColor
    },
    focused: {},
    notchedOutline: {},
})
```